# Why do we use division to find the value of 1 item?

Tags: arithmetic

If 4 apples is 16 dollars them 1 apple is 16÷4 dollars? Why do we use division here? What does it mean? If a car goes 60meter in 60 seconds,it goes 60÷60 m in 1s. How does that work? Why division and why not other operators like subtraction? How does this work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually called "cross-multiplication" and is a simple consequence of "proportionality".

But note that "proportionality" is an unspoken assumption in the two examples you give.

*If* the cost of apples is proportional to the number of apples, *then* you can divide the price by the number of apples to get the price of one apple.

But in some stores, 1 apple costs 5 dollars, a bundle of 2 apples costs 9 dollars (the store is happy that you bought two so they reduce the cost-per-apple), a bundle of 3 apples costs 14 dollars and a bundle of 4 apples costs 16 dollars.

Likewise, if a car is stopped and has to accelerate from speed 0 to maximum speed, maybe it goes 60 meter in 60 seconds, but it'll go a lot less than 1m in the first 1s at the beginning and a lot more than 1m in the last 1s at the end.